# Attach method on DbContext

Tags: entity-framework

My controller which uses the `Attach` method throws an error:

> DbContext does not contain a definition of Attach.

How can I fix this problem? I appreciate every help

```cs
public class ApplicationController : Controller
{
    ApplicationDbContext _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
    
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Delete(int Id)
    {
        Brand brand = _context.Brands
                              .Include(e => e.Products)
                              .Where(a => a.brand_id == Id)
                              .FirstOrDefault();

        return View(brand);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(Brand brand)
    {
        _context.Attach(brand);

        _context.Entry(brand).State = EntityState.Deleted;

        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: `Attach` is a member of `DbSet`, not `DbContext`.

Comment: And Entity Framework / EFCore is entirely separate from ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core.

Comment: `_context.Attach(brand);` should be `_context.Brands.Attach(brand);`